# using x-plane resources in blender

Tags: python, mesh, materials, objects, import

Can I import or directly use resources (scenery, meshes) from x-plane12 in blender 3.6? X-plane, world editor, and ac3d use resources such as object, meshes, scenery files to build realistic items like grass, buildings, highways, airports etc.  I would like to be able to use them in blender either directly (add a library taken from XP12 resources) or by importing them into blender, or by having python code to generate them.  Is there an app for that, a method or this even possible?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried an Internet search about this? Have you looked on the X-Plane forum? https://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/forums/ There is this on Github, but is says it is for up to Blender 3.3 https://github.com/X-Plane/XPlane2Blender/releases

Comment: Problem resolved.  Using GIMP I was able to convert x-plane textures (.dds) to ,jpg/.png files which I imported into blender.  Works just fine.  Also, object from x-plane or AC3D were easily imported into blender using .dae (collada) files or importing via .obj files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. Using GIMP I was able to convert x-plane textures (.dds) to ,jpg/.png files which I imported into blender. Works just fine. Also, object from x-plane or AC3D were easily imported into blender using .dae (collada) files or importing via .obj files